# why azure subnets don't have subnet.id param

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, subnet

I have the following simple code to generate 3 subnets:

```
$resourceGroupName = "Test1"
$location = "West Europe"
$VNetName = "Test-VM"
$VNetIPRange = "192.168.0.0/21"
$SubnetAName = "SubA"
$SubnetAIPRange = "192.168.0.0/24"
$SubnetBName = "SubB"
$SubnetBIPRange = "192.168.1.0/24"
$SubnetCName = "SubC"
$SubnetCIPRange = "192.168.2.0/24"

New-AzResourceGroup -name $resourceGroupName -Location $location -Verbose

# subnets & vnet
$subnets = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
    -Name $SubnetAName `
    -AddressPrefix $SubnetAIPRange `
    -Verbose
$vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork `
    -Name $VNetName `
    -AddressPrefix $VNetIPRange `
    -Subnet $subnets `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Location $location `
    -Verbose
Add-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
    -VirtualNetwork $vnet `
    -Name $SubnetBName `
    -AddressPrefix $SubnetBIPRange `
    -Verbose
Add-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
    -VirtualNetwork $vnet `
    -Name $SubnetCName `
    -AddressPrefix $SubnetCIPRange `
    -Verbose
Set-AzVirtualNetwork `
    -VirtualNetwork $vnet `
    -Verbose
```

The code runs successfully and is generating what is expected with exception of one thing. Only SubA has full information. For subnet B and C only the following configuration is like below:

```
                       {
                         "Name": "SubB",
                         "AddressPrefix": [
                           "192.168.1.0/24"
                         ]
                       }
```

With that i'm not able to reference Subnet Id like:

```
  -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[1].Id `
```

because the field is empty :(

Is something wrong in the code or should i reference subnet id somehow different?

I want to place some VMs in different subnets and only SubA is having SubnetID after i run above code.

```
                     {
                         "Delegations": [],
                         "Name": "SubA",
                         "Etag": "W/\"01baac3e-3fc3-400b-a6f1-64b08f5b45e7\"",
                         "Id": "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/Test1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtua
                     lNetworks/Test-VM/subnets/SubA",
                         "AddressPrefix": [
                           "192.168.0.0/24"
                         ],
                         "IpConfigurations": [],
                         "ServiceAssociationLinks": [],
                         "ResourceNavigationLinks": [],
                         "ServiceEndpoints": [],
                         "ServiceEndpointPolicies": [],
                         "InterfaceEndpoints": [],
                         "ProvisioningState": "Succeeded"
                       },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code and I can reproduce your issue, just use `Get-AzVirtualNetwork` after your code, then you will be able to get the `Id` of the other two subnets.

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $VNetName
$vnet.Subnets[1].Id
$vnet.Subnets[2].Id
```

[image]

Comment: yes, i need to declare the var once again. It's working fine. Thx!

Comment: To explain a bit more precisely, if for nothing else than my own understanding - the subnets you add don't get an Id until you add them to the VNET resource in Azure. And the $Vnet object you have is just a copy of the actual Vnet, not a pointer to it, so you need to get it again to have the Subnet Id's. Thanks for your explanation, it made me realise this and solved my issue. :)